# Numbering loop python

Tags: python, dictionary

Please I'm trying to number this loop:

```py
TopList = {'1350180828': 3, '1670937087': 2, '0743180828': 1, '9864937087': 8}

meg = "Top Referral List\n"
sort = sorted(TopList.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for info in sort:
    num = 1
    userlink = f'<a href="tg://user?id={info[0]}">{info[0]}</a>'
    meg += f"\n{num} {userlink} - {info[1]}\n"
    if len(sort) > 10:
        break
print(meg)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Top Referral List

1 9864937087 - 8

2 1350180828 - 3

3 1670937087 - 2

4 0743180828 - 1
```

Comment: What does it mean "to number this loop"?

Comment: Use [enumerate](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/#using-pythons-enumerate).

Comment: Please I just want to number it from 1 to 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
TopList = {'1350180828': 3, '1670937087': 2, '0743180828': 1, '9864937087': 8}
meg = "Top Refferal List\n"

sorted_keys = sorted(TopList, key=TopList.get, reverse=True)
for idx, key in enumerate(sorted_keys,1):
    userlink = f'<a href="tg://user?id={key}">{key}</a>'
    meg += f"\n{idx} {userlink} - {TopList.get(key)}\n"
print(meg)
```

Few things updates,

- Sorted the keys based on the value
- Iterate through the key and fetch the values during the iteration
- Used `enumerate` for the index values

Output:

```
Top Refferal List

1 <a href="tg://user?id=9864937087">9864937087</a> - 8

2 <a href="tg://user?id=1350180828">1350180828</a> - 3

3 <a href="tg://user?id=1670937087">1670937087</a> - 2

4 <a href="tg://user?id=0743180828">0743180828</a> - 1
```

**Edit:**

An updated version inspired by the comments of Blckknght &
Ben Grossmann.

```
TopList = {'1350180828': 3, '1670937087': 2, '0743180828': 1, '9864937087': 8}
meg = "Top Refferal List\n"

sorted_items = sorted(TopList.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for idx, (key, value) in enumerate(sorted_items, 1):
    userlink = f'<a href="tg://user?id={key}">{key}</a>'
    meg += f"\n{idx} {userlink} - {value}\n"
print(meg)
```

Comment: Using `enumerate` is definitely the way to go, but there's no need to switch to sorting only the keys, that's a separate unrelated choice. If you want to unpack enumerated items, you can do it in one go with `for num, (key, value) in enumerate(sorted_items))`

Comment: Very marginal suggestion: by using the optional `start` input to enumerate with `for idx, key in enumerate(sorted_keys,1):`, `idx` starts at 1, so you can print `idx` instead of `idx+1`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions both are incorporated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it isn't working is because you never increment the `num` variable.  So for each iteration it simply outputs a 1 every time. A simple solution would be to move the `num` variable outside of the loop and then increment it on each iteration after you have printed.

An alternative method would be to use `enumerate` which has already been demonstrated by RahulKP.  This is the better option for conciseness and readability.  The example below is just to demonstrate how you could make your code work

```
TopList = {'1350180828': 3, '1670937087': 2, '0743180828': 1, '9864937087': 8}

meg = "Top Refferal List\n"
sort = sorted(TopList.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
num = 1

for info in sort:
    userlink = f'<a href="tg://user?id={info[0]}">{info[0]}</a>'
    meg += f"\n{num} {userlink} - {info[1]}\n"
    num += 1
    if len(sort) > 10:
        break
print(meg)
```